# Old server is being retired, but need the web address that pointed to it to redirect to new server

Tags: domain-name-system, web-server

I've inherited an intranet site that gets hit by hundreds of different users per day.  They all know how to get to the page, simply type http://oldservername/site and enjoy.  We've got the site moved over to the new server and all is well.  The problem is that the old server is getting retired, and they want to do it ASAP.  The guy that built the site and ran it was supposed to be getting this done in March, but put it off until he left the company and now the admins are all over me about it due to deadlines.

Here is my dilemma.  If we shut down the old server, http://oldservername/site (the site everyone has bookmarked and has been running for over 10 years and is listed in all kinds of random documentation and SOPS), no longer works.  They would have to use http://newservername/site to get to the same page.  I told the admins this is far from ideal and asked for some DNS love and got shutdown.

They don't want to cname, they don't want to leave the old server on once the new server is deployed, and they don't care much because this was supposed to be done in March.

I just found out about it all this week and going back in time is not an option.  So without a cname, the old server still running with a warning page & redirect, or a time machine, what are my options?

Comment: Beat some sense into whoever told you you couldn't have the DNS changed.

Comment: @MichaelHampton seriously, this is exactly what it's supposed to be used for.  They claim they want to keep the old server with the same info while we run the new server for awhile.

Comment: I don't understand. You say that they want to retire the server ASAP and then you say that they want to keep it around for awhile. Which is it?

Comment: Obviously the list of people who need some sense beaten into them is much larger than we originally suspected.

Comment: @joeqwerty sorry, wasn't part of the problem so I wasn't clear on it.  They want to shut it down ASAP but hold on to it for a few weeks to make sure everything is going smoothly on the new server before getting rid of the old one entirely.

Comment: Would create a server alias on my webs-server. Such that all requests and site looks ups are successfully translated. Even after decommissioning the old server.  With server alias all requests will be processed by the new server.

Comment: Ask them how they were going to handle things had it been done in March. Then tell them to do it the same way.

Comment: DNS is the most recommended solution. Are the old and new servers in the same subnet? If yes, bring down the NIC on the old server and attach its IP to an alias interface on the new server.

Answer (score 1):

### The Good solution

The right solution is to get the CNAME. This is what DNS is designed to do. Buying donuts, yelling at people on the phone, and going to a manager are all appropriate actions in this case.

### The Bad solution

If this is not an option (I am not sure I can accept it, but I will try to move on). My only strategy would be to create a script that adds an entry to the users host file. This would essentially override the DNS server. If you have administrative control over any of the machines you can simply over wright or append to the host file. A little information about the hosts file can be found at http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/27350/beginner-geek-how-to-edit-your-hosts-file/

If you don't have admin rights over your users computers, I would replace the homepage on the old servers site with a download link and instructions to run your script. It sounds like you already have a counting solution, but if not add a counter to the old website so you can see and more importantly communicate with your bosses how many users will be affected if the machine is shut down. I would also try to get all documentation that has the old server name replaced with the new one.

This will end up causing a lot of work to support.

Answer (score 1):

You can use forward traffic, pending the dns propagation

execute on old server

```
echo 1 >/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination IPNewServer
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp -d IPNewServer --dport 80 -j MASQUERADE
```

but the final solution is to change the DNS and use 301 Moved Permanently on old server

.htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^oldservername/site  [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.oldservername/site [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newservername/site/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

and waits until your foot touches your beard to tell you that all visitors are changing their bookmarks